# OpenSolaris 2009.06 Vmware Tools

Tags: opensolaris, vmware-fusion

I have been trying to get vmware-tools installed in my Vmware Fusion OpenSolaris 2009.06 guest OS for some time now at no avail.  My experiences are the same as this thread on the [VMware forums](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/212833), and I was hoping someone here would have a solution.

Comment: You'll have to wait until VMware ports the X tools to the newer version of Xorg that comes with OpenSolaris 2009.06...  I don't think there's anything that can be done in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a bigger chance that you will not encounter any problems if you use VirtualBox instead, since it also comes from Sun.

Comment: Tried Virtualbox.  It was just clunky and slow compared to VMware IMO.

Comment: Try it again, a new version has come out.  If Solaris is important with regards to guest support you should use VirtualBox.   Nobody but Sun prioritizes Solaris as a guest os.

Answer (score 0):

I followed that exact fix in the forum post and it works well enough for me. It doesn't give you all the tools features for X, but it does give you clean guest shutdowns (and the eth driver in OpenSolaris 2009.06 already gives you 1000 throughput).

If you're looking for X support, you'll need to contact vmware.

Comment: The problem is, VMware charges for support.. :(